# HTML5-React-Video-Player: How to store my webm files somewhere like drobbox?

Tags: html, reactjs, video, dropbox

I am using `react-html5video` to make an HTML5 video react component. It works great when the `.webm` video file is stored locally:

```
const Movie = () =>
    <Video controls poster="BSCA_Logo.png">
        <source src="/videos/testing.webm"  type="video/webm" />
    </Video>
```

But I need my video to be hosted somewhere like Drobbox, Google Drive, or even YouTube. Googling says I can do this so I try like so:

```
const Movie = () =>
    <Video controls poster="BSCA_Logo.png">
        <source src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/mhlkapg2280e5/testing.webm"  type="video/webm" />
    </Video>
```

I then Tthe error I get, is "Video cannot be played in this browser."

I have even tried supporting multiple file formates:

```
const Movie = () =>
    <Video controls poster="BSCA_Logo.png">
        <source src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/mfbhlkapg2280e5/testing.webm" type="video/mp4" />
        <source src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/mfbhlkapg2280e5/testing.webm"  type="video/ogg" />
        <source src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/mfbhlkapg2280e5/testing.webm"  type="video/webm" />
    </Video>
```

If you can not use Drobbox for this purpose, what should I use to host my videos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The www links you have don't link to the file data itself, but rather a preview page for the file.

Try using the `raw` URL parameter as documented here:

https://www.dropbox.com/help/201

Comment: All my googling and I wasn't able to dig these docs up. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you much!